# Webpack fails to emit statements that depend on variables created by importScripts()

Tags: webpack, web-worker

I'm using webpack to bundle a webworker that in turn uses `importScripts()` to import require.js, but expressions that depend on the the imported requirejs are not emitted by Webpack. For example webpacking this script:

```js
importScripts('./require.js')
requirejs.config({...})
```

yields [a bundled module](https://gist.github.com/jdthorpe/51ef626691337706f05a78a5ccf31dbf): 
in which the call to `requirejs.config()` has been replaced with `undefined`.

Is there a way to get webpack to emit the call to `requirejs.config()`?

By way of background, here's my webpack config:

```
module.exports = [
    {
        devtool: 'cheap-source-map', 
        mode: 'development',
        target: 'webworker',
        entry: {
            'test-module': __dirname + '/test-module.js',
        },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            path: __dirname + '/dist',
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the requirejs to a new variable like so worked for some reason:

```js
importScripts('./require.js')
var _r = requirejs
_r.config({...})
```